# How to remove part of an URL in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I want to automatically remove `/feed` from the URL

For Example:

```
example.com/blog/something/feed/
```

to

```
example.com/blog/something/
```

Could someone tell me how to do this in Nginx?

Comment: The answer to your question is :
https://superuser.com/questions/435916/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-path-node

Comment: @ZarehKasparian it is working only if the path is after the domain. but my question is to remove the last path from the URL not the first.

Comment: its a regex, it looks the entire URL, and removes the mentioned part.